# How to correctly write lambda expression in fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have simple fetch in my react.js project:

```
export function getUserById(id) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:9000' },
        mode: 'no-cors',
    };
    var res = fetch("http://localhost:9000/user/"+id);//there should be a lot of strange lambdas..
    return res;
}
```

I use this function in other file:

```
var user = getUserById(userStr);
//some code
//more code

var email=user.mail;
var id = user.id;
```

Unfortunately - `res` is always Promise. I don't feel functional programming and react but I need to do it. I know that there should be some lambda expression, but I have no idea how to write them. As you see I need to take email and id from returning JSON.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is not that easy. Proper way (await returns promise!) is little bit more problematic. There is my solve ;) :

```
    return fetch("http://your.fancy.link").then((response) => response.json())
```

and

```
function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useContext(MyContext);
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);

    const readUrlParamsFromAuthentication = () => {
        var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var userStr = url.searchParams.get("user-id");
        var userId = null;
        var userEmail = null;
      
        if (userStr) {
            
            getUserById(userStr).then(user=>
                {
                   
                    localStorage.setItem('email', user.email);
                    setState({ email: user.email, isLogged: true });
                    console.log("TUTAAAAJ");
                    console.log(user.email,user.id,state.isLoggedIn);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            );
            console.log("UserStr");

        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        readUrlParamsFromAuthentication();
    }, [])

there should be your return html ;)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` the fetch call.

See [this example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#rewriting_promise_code_with_asyncawait).

```
export async function getUserById(id) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:9000' },
        mode: 'no-cors',
    };
    var res = fetch("http://localhost:9000/user/"+id);//there should be a lot of strange lambdas..
    return res;
}


var user = await getUserById(userStr);
//some code
//more code

var email=user.mail;
var id = user.id;
```

Edit: You don’t need to `await` the fetch call, you only need to `await getUserById(userStr)`.

Comment: This actually doesn't make a difference. You've had to make getUserById async to await the fetch, so the result of calling the function is still a promise. And you can't await that outside an async function.

Comment: Still, you need to wait for a promise to resolve.

You can call `await getUserById(userStr)` inside an async function, or `.then()` it.

Comment: They already _had_ a promise to resolve, because res was the promise fetch returned.

Comment: Oh I see, so the await on the fetch is unnecessary.

Comment: Without the `await` there's no need for the function to be `async`. There's no difference between returning a value and a promise of the same value from an `async` function, because either way the function returns a promise of that value. And either is equivalent to a non-`async` function that returns a promise of the value.

Comment: @anaknickerbocker is right. I needed to use then ;) My answer is posted below